# Convert NSDate to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsdate

I have the following:

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:[sDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Z" withString:@"-0000"]];
[df release];
```

I would like the output string to be "9/20/10"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

This will display it in the users settings (but in a similar way), so for me results will be 7/28/10

Comment: hey superb!! suffer 1 day with this forgot "NSDateFormatterBehavior10"

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this way :

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSString *result = [df stringFromDate:date];
[df release];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try

```
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: i have tried this solution but getting crash on this line.